# How to use regex with multiple data formats

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract reference CVEs from a website that I monitor.  My regex code was working when the format on row0 was like this -- (Ref. #8957501) (CVE-2015-3600), but it broke when the format changed to this -- (Ref #555237/92073/CVE-2015-9042)

How do I extract the CVE string using both formats?

Here is my current regex code:

```
cve_pattern = re.compile(r'(CVE-1999-\d{4,7}|CVE-(200[0-9])-\d{4,7}|CVE-(201[0-9])-\d{4,7})', re.IGNORECASE)
    for cve_number_pattern_match in cve_pattern.finditer(row[0]):
        if cve_number_pattern_match is not None:
            logger.info(cve_number_pattern_match.group(0) + " is located on row " + str(row_num))
            cve_number_list[row_num] = cve_number_pattern_match.group(0)
```

Comment: Try a mere `r'\bCVE[\d-]+'`. Or `r'\bCVE-\d+(?:-\d+)?'`

Comment: Yes, that worked.

Comment: I added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
r'\bCVE[\d-]+'
```

to match a word boundary, `CVE` substring, and  1+ digits or `-`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hoefAU/1).

Or, you may  use a more precise

```
r'\bCVE-\d+(?:-\d+)?'
```

**Details**:

- `\b` - leading word boundary
- `CVE-` - `CVE-` substring
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `(?:-\d+)?` - an optional sequence of:

  - `-` - a hyphen
  - `\d+` - 1 or more digits.

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/hoefAU/2).